# How to install all VS Code workspace extensions programatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When VS Code opens in a folder with `.vscode/extensions.json` present the user has the option to `Install All` recommended extensions.

How can the `Install All` function be invoked programatically (i.e. without human interaction) using the command line or VS Code API?

[image: popup]

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look like the "Install All" action is associated with a command you could call via the `vscode.commands` API.

The easiest solution is probably to parse `.vscode/extensions.json` yourself. You could then simply run `code --install-extension <extension-id>` for each of the extension IDs you find.

Comment: It worked well for me. I only needed to add .vscode/extensions.json into my project.